# Handles missing in the graph editor

Tags: bezier-curves, graph-editor

It's impossible for me to manipulate handles in the graph editor. The numbers in the scroll bars on the side, are missing, and if I scroll in, the bottom scroll bar just expands.

[image]

Comment: Try pressing the A, then period key on the number pad, or in the view menu, press "view selected"

Comment: Thanks a lot, man! Both for your help with the editor and for correcting my spectacular english.

Comment: I'm glad to help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're zoomed out a lot.

To fix this, press <kbd>A</kbd> to select everything, and then press <kbd>Numpad .</kbd> to view selected.

Comment: You may also press Home button. It works the same way.